# SQL Select - where subquery has multiple row

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I'm trying to build a simple select that prompts for childfield and returns results for parent field. In a majority of our situations only one parent is listed but when multiple I get the 'single-row subquery returns more than one row' error that I'm not certain how to work out of.

```
Select Date, location, MiscData, ChildField, ParentField
from Maintable t1
where childfield = (select t2.parentfield from maintable t2 where t2.childfield = @('prompt', childfield))
```

As I mentioned for a vast majority of our data will only have one parent field but when there's more than one it error's out. I've started tripping over my own feet so to speak and possibly thinking about this in entirely the wrong way and could use some pointers or at least a push in the right direction.

Just for a little more clarification on my code; the parentfield was once contained in the childfield and that is the results I'm trying to obtain. And when the parentfield was a childfield it would have no parentfield.

I made the below sample set to try to provide an idea of some of the items I'm dealing with. With this set one might visualize how more than one parent can makeup a child which is why we may have multiple row. "and no this isn't for a bar - just a sample set"

### Sample Data set:

[image]

Comment: So what is the desired result when there are more than 1 parent rows? Return all?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - it would be ideal to see all and I could order by date

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I added a sample set to the inquiry, take a look

Comment: So, if the table contained the eight rows you are showing and you ask for 'cup1', the query shall show the last four rows (those whith Cildfield = 'Johnny Walker'). Yes?

Comment: The tags are incorrect. Which DBMS are you using? Oracle is another DBMS than PostgreSQL. And Oracle's database programming language PL/SQL has nothing to do with this at all.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks for that you were right on my tags. This is an Oracle Database 12c .
Also yes if ask for cup1 I would get those with child field Johnny Walker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed some of the suggestions provided and the best I was able to work from was by Rajat.

```
Select Date, location, MiscData, ChildField, ParentField
    from Maintable t1
    INNER JOIN maintable t2 ON t2.parentfield = t1.childfield 
    where t2.childfield = @('prompt', childfield))
```

I wasn't receiving any data which I found out was due to the infamous 'space' character that threw everything out of wack.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select Date, location, MiscData, ChildField, ParentField
    from Maintable t1
    where childfield in (select t2.parentfield from maintable t2 where t2.childfield = @('prompt', t1.childfield))
```

Comment: I tried that it doesn't error out but it also didn't yield any results

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for this problem is that your subquery returning multiple resultsets

There are various solutions for it let's see below the solution one by one.

## 1 TOP 1 in the subquery

```
Select Date, location, MiscData, ChildField, ParentField
from Maintable t1
where childfield = (select TOP(1) t2.parentfield from maintable t2 where t2.childfield = @('prompt', childfield))
```

## 2 Inner join instead of a subquery

```
 Select Date, location, MiscData, ChildField, ParentField
    from Maintable t1
    INNER JOIN maintable t2 ON t2.parentfield = t1.childfield 
    where t2.childfield = @('prompt', childfield))
```

I hope the above solution might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is a bit hard to understand, but looking at your data, it seems some of your rows have been replaced with other ones.

```
+------------+----------+------------+-------------+
|    date    | location | childfield | parantfield |
+------------+----------+------------+-------------+
| 2020-05-01 | A-old    | abc        |             |
| 2020-05-02 | B-old    | abc        | def         |
| 2020-05-02 | B-new    | def        |             |
| 2020-05-03 | C-old    | def        |             |
| 2020-05-04 | D-old    | abc        | ghi         |
| 2020-05-04 | D-new    | ghi        |             |
+------------+----------+------------+-------------+
```

If you are looking for 'abc', you want ...

- the first row ('A-old'), because it is still abc and has not been replaced.
- the third row ('B-new'), which is replacing the second (parentfield->childfield, same date)
- the sixth row ('D-new'), which is replacing the fifth (parentfield->childfield, same date)

```
+------------+----------+
|    date    | location |
+------------+----------+
| 2020-05-01 | A-old    |
| 2020-05-02 | B-new    |
| 2020-05-04 | D-new    |
+------------+----------+
```

If this is so, then I'd recommend a self outer join:

```
select
  t1.date,
  coalesce(t2.location, t1.location) as location
from maintable t1
left join maintable t2 on t2.childfield = t1.parentfield and t2.date = t1.date
where t1.childfield = 'abc'
order by t1.date;
```